# Rails No route matches [GET] "/assets/font-awesome"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, font-awesome

I have a project and in production server it rise exception. (It's all ok on local host).

```
I, [2016-12-20T11:59:24.437623 #2835]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-52453754952f43a7e1f68a01422139fb.woff2?v=4.3.0" for 127.0.0.1 at 201$
F, [2016-12-20T11:59:24.439527 #2835] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont-52453754952f43a7e1f68a01422139fb.woff2")
```

I don't understand why on local host it's ok, but in production it gives error, and how to fix it.

Comment: It seems one of your style sheets is requesting a font file and not finding it. In this case Fontawesome which is usually used for fonticons. Did you check your stylesheets for font imports that might not resolve? some gems also have issues too, such as https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/issues/48

Comment: @mlabarca but I don't quite get it. it work well for some time on production and then it's broke. but still it's ok son local host.

Comment: This 'working on development but not on production' thing with assets is usually due to precompilation. Since assets are only precompiled on production, in development the link to your asset might be 'fontawesome-webfont-1.woff2'  but after precompilation this changes, and hence the issues start. Do you use any kind of gems to manage the fontawesome font import?

Comment: @mlabarca the only one is gem 'rails-assets-font-awesome'

Comment: Try deleting the assets and do 'rake assets:precompile' and see if you get the errors

Comment: not sure where you are hosting your production environment but this could also be the issue where some hosting platforms do not allow local file storage and some times things get cleaned up when you were not expecting it. You should be able to check if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for using font-awesome added to rails project with npm or yarn. Just set $fa-font-path varibale before import 'font-awesome' that pointing to simple asset from `node_modules` folder.

```
$fa-font-path: "font-awesome/fonts" !default;

@import 'font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in Rails 5 and I solved it by adding `config.assets.debug = true` in the corresponding environment.